# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

I just upgraded my server's PHP version to PHP 7.4.1 and now getting this error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

```
public static function read($id)
{
    $Row = MySQL::query("SELECT `Data` FROM `cb_sessions` WHERE `SessionID` = '$id'", TRUE);
    
    # http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#120589
    //check to see if $session_data is null before returning (CRITICAL)
    if(is_null($Row['Data']))
    {
        $session_data = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $session_data = $Row['Data'];
    }
    
    return $session_data;
}
```

What is the fix for PHP 7.4 ?

Comment: ```if($Row['Data'] == false || is_null($Row['Data']))``` fixed it but am wondering if this is the right fix.

Comment: Depends on what `MySQL::query()` returns when no results were found.

Comment: If no results are found then it returns false , if there is a result then it returns the first row as an assoc array, ```public static function query($sql, $returnRow = FALSE)``` - the 2nd parameter is TRUE in this case.

Comment: So, you should check if $Row is false first, only then try to access any other value.

Comment: Just a heads up, Collection from at least Laravel 5.4 - 5.8 are incompatible with PHP 7.4, and crashes with this error.

Comment: If version 6 runs on PHP 7.4, then I don't think they would update 5.x

Comment: I recently got also this error message in Wordpress after upgrading to PHP 8.0. After downgrading to PHP 7.4, error message disappeared.

Comment: I got that error on a Wordpress site when upgrading my PHP version from 7.4 to 8.2 but it turns out that it only happened in my local environment, and it neither happened in my staging nor production environments. I'll have to assume that our hosting at WP Engine already had a fix for this configured on their end which wasn't present in my local installation.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Easy with PHP  [`??` null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

```
return $Row['Data'] ?? 'default value';
```

Or you can use as such

```
$Row['Data'] ??= 'default value';
return $Row['Data'];
```

Comment: For PHP versions < 7 you can also use a ternary statement: `$Row['data'] = isset($Row['data']) ? $Row['data'] : 'default';`

Comment: Wow, It's working... $Row['data'] = isset($Row['data']) ? $Row['data'] : 'default';

Answer (score 12):

If your query does not return a row, then your variable $Row will be filled with false,
so you can test if the variable has a value before try to access any index inside it:

```
if($Row){
  if(is_null($Row['Data']))
  {
      $session_data = '';
  }...
```