# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php

I get the following error when I try to open a new page from the menu.
in PHP7.4

I think that mssql_num_rows() for checking if the number of rows is greater than zero will solve the problem but I can't implement it in this code due to my poor  knowledge with PHP and my lack of time.

```
public function getCompany()
    {
        /** @var $Params array */
        $Params = $this->getURLParams();

        $sql = sprintf("
            SELECT CompanyName.ID
            FROM CompanyName, SiteTree
            WHERE CompanyName.Slug = '%s' and CompanyName.CompanyPageID = SiteTree.ID and SiteTree.URLSegment = '%s'
         ", $Params['Action'], $Params['URLSegment']);

        /** @var $row array */
        $row = DB::query($sql)->current();

        /** @var $Company CompanyName */

        $Company = DataObject::get_by_id(CompanyName::class, intval($row['ID']));

        if (!$Company instanceof CompanyName) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var $CompanyPage CompanyPage */
        $CompanyPage = $Company->CompanyPage();

        if ($CompanyPage->getField('URLSegment') != $Params['URLSegment'])
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $Company;
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: With 99% certainty. The SQL query is wrong.

Comment: Works fine in live server, the problem only in my local it is related to PHP 7.4 version

Comment: What exactly is the output of your $sql? (Do an echo $sql right after your SQL-statement is set.

Comment: What version of PHP you use on the live server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674903/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-php-7-4)

Comment: No I tried it ,
echo $sql give me :

SELECT CompanyName.ID FROM CompanyName, SiteTree WHERE CompanyName.Slug = '' and CompanyName.CompanyPageID = SiteTree.ID and SiteTree.URLSegment = 'personal'

Comment: And that SQL-query works works locally on your SQL database? (not involving PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I changed :

```
$Company = DataObject::get_by_id(CompanyName::class, intval($row['ID']));
```

to

`$Company = DataObject::get_by_id(CompanyName::class, intval($row['ID']??='default value'));`