# Argument 2 passed to yii\db\conditions\HashConditionBuilder::build() must be of the type array, string given in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

when i trying to make join between two tables i get error.

here is my controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $view = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['id', 'user_id', 'body', 'title'])
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'blog.user_id','users.id')
        ->where(['blog.id' => $id])
        ->one();

    return $this->render('view', compact('view'));
}
```

here is my view

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2><?= $view['name'] . ' ' . $view['surname'] ?></h2>
            <h3><?= $view['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?= $view['body']; ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo yii::$app->homeUrl; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Back </a>
            <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $view['id']], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On prima vista, it's obvious that you had forgot the `from` clause of the `QueryBuilder`.

Take a look into this:

```
$view = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['id', 'user_id', 'body', 'title'])
        ->from('blog') // this is your from clause of the query
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'blog.user_id = users.id')
        ->where(['blog.id' => $id])
        ->one();
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer. i tried your method but i get this error (Argument 2 passed to yii\db\conditions\HashConditionBuilder::build() must be of the type array, string given)

Comment: I have edited my answer, check out the `join` clause also.

Comment: yeah but now i got this error (Trying to access array offset on value of type bool)

Comment: This is something completely different from defining your query builder. I think what I had described should work properly.

Comment: what you had described its works very good. but i dont understant why  im getting this error? i never get errors like this in Laravel

Comment: `Trying to access array offset on value of type bool)` I think this comes from your view. You should check if specific key exists in your  $view data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674903/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-php-7-4.