# On array Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in php 7.4

Tags: php

In php 7.4 strict mode I have this error

PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
I do not understand exactly the problem

Thank you

```
public array $billing;
```

the line where the error appear :

```
$this->billing = [
        'firstname' => $billing_address['entry_firstname'],            
        'state' => (!is_null($billing_address['entry_state']) ? $billing_address['entry_state'] : $billing_address['zone_name']),
        'zone_id' => $billing_address['entry_zone_id'],
        'country' => array('id' => $billing_address['countries_id'], 'title' => $billing_address['countries_name'], 'iso_code_2' => $billing_address['countries_iso_code_2'], 'iso_code_3' => $billing_address['countries_iso_code_3']),
      ];
```

Comment: It's six lines, which line __exactly__? Also `var_dump($billing_address)`

Comment: the error appears on all the lines

Comment: place code about `$billing_address[]` so we can help you where is actual problem.

Comment: find a solution by if (isset($billing_address) { ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674903/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-php-7-4)

Comment: Hello @Raph, welcome to stackoverflow. Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that you *use a variable as array, but actually it is bool*.

**I guess that `$billing_address` is false instead of array.**

It got false while you were trying to fetch if from DB or other source.
So you should always check if you have a value there and put a default value like empty array []. Or throw an exception "billing address not found".