# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\wp-content\pluginson line 93

Tags: php, wordpress

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\wp-content\plugins\skape_helper_plugin\includes\vendors\custom-fonts\custom-fonts.php on line 93
line 93-
$fonts = $fonts[ 'cus.tom-typekit-font-details' ];
total code

```
<?php

/**
 * @author: VLThemes
 * @version: 1.0
 */

if ( ! class_exists( 'VLThemesAddCustomFonts' ) ) {
    class VLThemesAddCustomFonts {

    /**
     * New fonts array
     */
    public $new_fonts = array();

    /**
     * Children array
     */
    public static $children = array();

    /**
     * Variants array
     */
    public static $variants = array();

    /**
     * The single class instance.
     * @var $_instance
     */
    private static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * Main Instance
     * Ensures only one instance of this class exists in memory at any one time.
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
            self::$_instance->init_hooks();
            self::$_instance->prepare_custom_fonts();
            self::$_instance->prepare_typekit_fonts();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        // We do nothing here!
    }

    /**
     * Init hooks
     */
    public function init_hooks() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'get_custom_fonts' ) );
        add_filter( 'vlthemes/kirki_font_choices', array( $this, 'add_custom_fonts' ), 20 );
    }

    /**
     * Get custom fonts from Bsf_Custom_Fonts_Taxonomy
     */
    public function get_custom_fonts() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'Bsf_Custom_Fonts_Taxonomy' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        update_option( 'vlthemes-custom-fonts', Bsf_Custom_Fonts_Taxonomy::get_fonts() );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare custom fonts
     */
    public function prepare_custom_fonts() {

        $fonts = get_option( 'vlthemes-custom-fonts' );

        if ( ! empty( $fonts ) ) {
            foreach ( $fonts as $font => $key ) {
                $this->new_fonts[$font] = array(
                    'id' => $font,
                    'text' => $font,
                    'variant' => array( '200', '300', '400', '400italic', '500', '500italic', '600', '600italic', '700', '700italic', '800', '800italic', 'regular', 'italic' )
                );
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Prepare Typekit fonts
     */
    public function prepare_typekit_fonts() {

    $fonts = get_option( 'custom-typekit-fonts' );
    $fonts = $fonts[ 'cus.tom-typekit-font-details' ];

        if ( ! empty( $fonts ) ) {

            foreach ( $fonts as $key => $font ) {

                $this->new_fonts[$key] = array(
                    'id' => implode( $font[ 'css_names' ] ),
                    'text' => $font[ 'family' ],
                    'variant' => $font[ 'weights' ]
                );

            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Check is font in array
     */
    public function is_in_array( $array, $key, $key_value ) {
        $within_array = 'no';

        foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {

            if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
                $within_array = $this->is_in_array( $v, $key, $key_value );

                if ( $within_array == 'yes' ) {
                    break;
                }

            } else {

                if ( $v == $key_value && $k == $key ) {
                    $within_array = 'yes';
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        return $within_array;
    }

    /**
     * Add custom fonts to Kirki
     */
    public function add_custom_fonts( $custom_choice ) {

        if ( ! empty( $this->new_fonts ) ) {

            foreach ( $this->new_fonts as $new_font ) {

                if ( $this->is_in_array( self::$children, 'id', $new_font[ 'id' ] ) == 'no' ) {

                    self::$children[] = array(
                        'id' => $new_font[ 'id' ],
                        'text' => $new_font[ 'text' ]
                    );

                    self::$variants[$new_font[ 'id' ]] = $new_font[ 'variant' ];

                }

            }

        }

        $custom_choice[ 'families' ][ 'custom' ] = array(
            'text' => esc_attr__( 'Custom Fonts', 'vlthemes' ),
            'children' => self::$children
        );

        $custom_choice[ 'variants' ] = self::$variants;

        return $custom_choice;

    }

}

function vlthemes_add_custom_fonts() {
    return VLThemesAddCustomFonts::instance();
}

vlthemes_add_custom_fonts();

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674903/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-php-7-4)

Comment: Try using `if( isset($fonts[ 'cus.tom-typekit-font-details' ])) { $fonts = $fonts[ 'cus.tom-typekit-font-details' ] } else{ ...`