# Upgrading from PHP 7.4 to 8.0 bool/null errors

Tags: php

I have managed to fix one problem (found answer on google search) but this one still appears on my site:

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /usr/home/.../template-series.php on line 103 
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /usr/home/.../template-series.php on line 103 
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /usr/home/.../template-series.php on line 105 
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /usr/home/.../template-series.php on line 105
```

```
                            if ($choice == 'choice1') {
                                $img1 = get_sub_field('series2_rep_img1');
```

```
LINE 103:                           $thumb1 = $img1['sizes']['foundation-small'];
                                    $img2 = get_sub_field('series2_rep_img2');

LINE 105:                           $thumb2 = $img2['sizes']['foundation-small'];
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: What does `var_dump($img1, $img2)` show?

Comment: Have you set the image on your ACF fields ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674903/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-php-7-4)

Comment: I dont know much about PHP etc. Where var_dump... is located?

Comment: https://www.php.net/var_dump